# A basic question on random variables

Tags: probability

Consider the following:

- $x$ is an instantiation of a Bernoulli random variable over $\pm1$.
- $y: y^2-1=0$, so $y=\pm1$.

How do we explain the difference between $x$ and $y$ to a high school student? I know that $x$ is the outcome of a random experiment and $y$ is deterministic. Is there a much more intuitive way of explaining this?

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest that focusing on the difference between "random experiment" and determinism might be the key.  In both cases, numerical values are being associated with the underlying concept, which illustrates the power of mathematics in describing our world using a common "language."  For example, you might say someone is 2 meters tall and has 2 siblings.  Both use "2" as a way to describe the quantity and people understand what 2 of something is, but someone's height and number of relatives are not comparable concepts.

Likewise, in the random experiment, one outcome is assigned the value +1 and the other is -1, as a way to numerically characterize the results for convenience - for example if you were flipping a coin as the random experiment but wanted to create a random walk model from this, you could associate heads with +1 and tails with -1, and thus be able to plot distances on a graph.

On the other hand, in the $y^2-1$ case, $\pm1$ refers to the solutions of a particular algebraic equation, a different concept, but one can use the common language of math to represent the result.

I hope this helps.